# change selinux property of a file?

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permission denied in vhost document root](https://serverfault.com/questions/409464/permission-denied-in-vhost-document-root)

Apache cant process my files due to forbidden error, searching resulted that it might be because of selinux, how can I change selinux policy of a specific file?

It's Centos 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restorecon -Fv /path/to/your/file
```