# Checking problems with running a new site on CentOS

Tags: centos, virtualhost, httpd

I have an empty CentOS 6.3 box. I need to run multiple websites from this server. Things that I have done so far are:

1. Installed Apache, MySQL, PHP and PHP modules by following [this article.](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.3-lamp)
2. I created a test file index.html inside the /var/www/html/ folder and tried to visit the default site by pointing my browser to the server's IP. But it didn't show anything.
3. I commented the line "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" inside the httpd.conf file and added Virtualhost settings as:

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/abc.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/abc.com">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Note** abc.com above is the hostname of my server and I connect to the server as root@abc.com

4. I created folders /vhosts/abc.com and placed a file index.php in it
5. I then restarted the server using service httpd restart

Pointing my browser to either the server's IP or abc.com, shows me a "Page cannot be displayed". If I try to check /var/log/httpd/access_log or /var/log/httpd/error_log, it shows me nothing.

**UPDATE:** My /etc/hosts file is like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
108.175.9.103 abc.com
```

and /etc/sysconfig/network file is:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```

How do I check where does the problem lie ? What possibly could be wrong here ?

**Update2:** My iptables file looks like:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

After the las line (after COMMIT), I tried to add:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But a restart of the iptables service throws an error.

Comment: whats the output of: service httpd status

Comment: httpd (pid  <pid value>) is running...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to open port 80 in the iptables firewall

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If this works then you need to save the state of the firewall

```
service iptables save
```

If this works, as it looks like you're going to use document roots outside the standard /var/www then you should also need to change the SELinux context for the new root so look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/409464/permission-denied-in-vhost-document-root/409488#409488) for how to do that.

Comment: Before I try the above solution, once I open the port 80, after that can I have as many websites as I want, in the same manner as explained in the question ? By creating VirtualHost settings ?

Comment: Using [name based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) it would yes.

Comment: I tried to run the above command, but it throws an error saying "-J requires an argument". I also tried to modify the iptables files (updated the question with my steps) but it didn't work.

Comment: @gentrobot: sorry typo should be `-j` (lowercase)

Comment: Excellent ! It worked for me :) Thanks a lot @lain

Comment: @lain: How about I create all my websites inside /var/www/html/domain1 and /var/www/html/domain2 ? That way, I will not have to go through the second part of your answer.

Comment: @gentrobot: That would work.

Comment: I have already done that. It surely works ! I believe in the policy that the SE sites follow, i.e. try and do and come up with a problem, rather than asking a 'HOW TO'. I am really thankful for your guidelines and help.